# Setting different values for app_name string resource (To have a different App name) for different product flavors

Tags: android, android-resources, android-productflavors

```
productFlavors {
    dev {

        applicationId project.property('ANDROID_BUILD_APPLICATIONID_DEV')

        resValue('string', 'app_name', 'dddd')
    }
}
```

I'd like to have different names based on different flavors , so I use resValue like above . But I only got the package name , not "dddd" , and I have already removed app_name in strings.xml .
Is there any trick here ?

Answer (score 1):

To have different app names for different flavors:

**Create a string.xml as follows for each flavor (under the flavor's own src folder):**
(taking `dev` flavor as example here)

Folder structure in your project should be as follows:

```
app
---src
   ---main
      ---res
         ----values
             ----string.xml
   ---dev
      ---res
         ----values
             ----string.xml
```

Set the String value for `app_name` in the `string.xml` under each flavor as you want it.

String resources in flavor's resource folder override the string resources in main's resource folder. Just putting `app_name` in the flavor specific `string.xml` is enough. You do not need to copy all string resources from the main src folder unless you want to use a different value for the flavor.

Dont remove `app_name` from `strings.xml` in your `main` folder. (Which you mentioned you already did - in your question). revert it if you go with this approach. It will serve as a fallback string resource if you do not explicitly set a separate resource for some other flavor.

If you are talking about suffixing `dddd` to package name use `applicationIdSuffix` as seen below:

```
   productFlavors {
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dddd"
        }
```

Comment: This works indeed . But it just didn't solve my problem .

Comment: what is the problem you are mentioning apart from setting separate names? do you want to suffix `dddd` to the package name?